# http://localhost not working in firefox but it works in IE

Tags: firefox, iis-7.5

While i was trying to browse my project through IIS i was not able to view it in firefox , but able to view in IE. Can anybody solve this issue?

steps i have done...

1. I have hosted my project on IIS
2. Browse like http://localhost/myproject in firefox and IE

but able to do in IE but cannot access this in Firefox.
But if i put my machine name or local IP address in place of localhost i was able to browse. I am pretty confused with this issue? Can anybody help me to tackle this issue?

Comment: check if you have a wampserver installed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your hosts file in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

It may have a line like that

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Try uncommenting it if it is, or you may find something wrong in this file. It is the file your browsers read to match names to IPs and override DNS info.

Comment: Sometimes you will have to restart your browsers once you've made a modification in your hosts file.

Comment: Thanks Kodiak for your answer, but it didn't help me in solving this issue. I think it may be some other issue.

Comment: This is not experiencing by me alone. its also occuring to my collegues

Comment: - finally i resolved the issue by adding localhost into the firefox exception list